# How to use JQuery and moment.js to automatically change date locale?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I want to change a fixed timestamp in English to German automatically with moment.js.
The timestamp looks like the following:

`<time class="entry-timeago timestamp" datetime="2016-09-06">a month ago</time>`

For this I have added the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/locale/de.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">   
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
moment.locale(language);

  $('.timestamp').each(function (i, date) {
    var $date = $(date);

    $date.html(
      moment($date.attr('datetime'))
        .format('ll')
    );
  });
</script>
```

With this code I still cannot see a difference (even if I set `moment.locale('de');` manually) and I wonder why.
Thanks for help.

Comment: It seems fine and it works for me, can you provide a snippet or a fiddle showing the issue?

Comment: I have implemented it on [my blog](https://www.peleke.de/) without success.